# Android splash screen issue

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash screen for android however am getting the below error:

2024-01-12 10:48:41.126 22827-22827 AndroidRuntime  com.almowafarati.app `your text`E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.almowafarati.app, PID: 22827
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.almowafarati.app/com.almowafarati.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

**Here is my themes xml: **

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.Almowafarati" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Almowafarati" parent="Base.Theme.Almowafarati" />

    <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/avd_anim</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Base.Theme.Almowafarati</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**My Manifest: **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.almowafarati.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWeb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the splash screen
        installSplashScreen();

        // Initialize WebView
        myWeb = findViewById(R.id.myWeb);
        myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWeb.loadUrl("https://almowafarati.com");
    }

    // Define the splash screen installation method
    private void installSplashScreen() {
    }
}
```

I tried changing the theme but that didn't fix the issue as well, the splash screen appears then the app immediately terminates

Comment: Where is `Theme.SplashScreen` come from?

Comment: from the dependency implementation"androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1" I believe

Comment: Could you also share the crash log, Android SDK version and the target device android version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Answer (score 0):

Ok found your problem:

This is from the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen) of SplashScreen:

> In the onCreate method the starting activity, call installSplashScreen
> just before super.onCreate(). You also need to make sure that
> postSplashScreenTheme is set to the application's theme.
> Alternatively, this call can be replaced by Activity#setTheme if a
> SplashScreen instance isn't needed.

So 2 things to fix:

Set the application back to your main theme, the same as `postSplashScreenTheme`:

```
android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.Almowafarati"
```

Call `installSplashScreen()` before `setContentView`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// This can be replaced by Activity.setTheme since you are using Java, so this kotlin extension method is not available
installSplashScreen();

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: I made the above changes and am still getting the same error, here is the logcat:

2024-01-12 13:34:10.436 25753-25753 AndroidRuntime          com.almowafarati.app                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.almowafarati.app, PID: 25753
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.almowafarati.app/com.almowafarati.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem, see the crash, and the above changes fix it successfully so don't know if there's something missing. I am currently using Kotlin so I can call `installSplashScreen` extension directly

Comment: My current MainActivity is Java should I change it to Kotlin?

Comment: I don't know, cannot find anything about Splashscreen core library code for Java, so it only supports Kotlin I guess. But you should migrate to Kotlin, Android Studio makes it easy for the transition, and Kotlin is awesome too

Comment: I created a new project from scratch & used Kotlin but am still getting the same error :( if you don't mind could you share the files you created with me or tell me which base application theme you're using?

Comment: This is my main application theme `<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`. Deep into the parent tree, it inherits from Theme.Appcompat

Comment: same issue! am going crazy! 

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.Almowafarati" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   </style>

    <style name="Theme.Almowafarati" parent="Base.Theme.Almowafarati" />

    <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Base.Theme.Almowafarati</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: done found the problem I changed class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

to class MainActivity : Activity() {

Answer (score 0):

Changed class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { to class MainActivity : Activity() { and problem got fixed